# How to route VPN traffic even on machine running VPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

We have 2 servers: server1, server2
My pc is client1
We have VPN server running on server1 with IP 1.2.3.4 (Just example)
We want to hide some services behind VPN including sshd and vnc server

Part of vpn config:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "remote-gateway vpn_server_ip"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

Part of iptables configuration:

```
PRIVATE=10.8.0.0/24
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $PRIVATE -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
```

What is working:
If I am connected into VPN
I am able to connect to server2 with ssh (let's say to IP 1.2.3.5) and in last login message from SSH I can see Address of VPN server instead of my ip.

```
ssh server2
```

will result:

```
Last login: Tue Aug  2 15:55:46 2016 from server1
```

But when i am connecting to our server1, which is the one running VPN I have still my IP there (I have it enabled in firewall too):

```
ssh server1
```

output:

```
Last login: Tue Aug  2 15:57:38 2016 from client1
```

I want there server IP 1.2.3.4 instead of client1 IP. So I can accept only packets from server1 in our firewall.
This is now working for server2, but not on server1 because POSTROUTING affects only output packets.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange As it stands, your question is very confused. You should refer to servers by a name or acronym, not `one or the other`, and state what you mean by `connecting`: do you mena you use an external pc, first connect to the VPN server, then to another pc? You should also clarify what you wish to accomplish, which is by no means clear now.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to try it make less confusing.

Comment: I think I can achieve required solution via some ovewriting of DNS to server1 in which I say it have IP 10.8.0.1from tun0 device. But I want to achieve it without need of running own DNS.

Comment: You may try by dropping `-o eno1` in your iptables rule.

Comment: That doen't work. I think there is needed to use SNAT or something because POSTROUTING is done too late. But I don't know how.